# FCM notifications do not arrive after a while

Tags: android, push-notification

my problem in sending notifications is that after sending notifications in a time, the notifications that are sent are no longer received but if the instance is deleted and a new token is created, notifications that have not been sent arrive. Our app is a frequent use of notifications and massive, recommendations of this thanks.

This is for a massive use of push notifications to request a transport service like Uber

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. As it is written right now, your question can not be answered.

Comment: ok thanks, I already resolved it